# Github User Pages and Custom Domain Issue

Tags: github, github-pages, custom-domain

I have a couple of issues I believe are related regarding githubpages.

First, when trying to create my user page by naming the repo the same as my username, I expect the url to be this `myusername.github.io`.Instead it looks like this `myusername.github.io/myusername`.

I have been to work around this by naming my repo `myusername.github.io`, which produces the correct URL.

Now, I want to create a custom domain with this user page. I can use my custom domain with the above workaround, but this now affects all other repos which use github pages. For example, I setup `myusername.github.io` to use `mycustomdomain.com`. But now I have another project that uses gh pages called `someotherproject`. The url now redirects to `mycustomdomain.com/someotherproject` instead of `someotherproject.github.io`.

Is this working correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But now I have another project that uses gh pages called someotherproject. The url now redirects to mycustomdomain.com/someotherproject instead of someotherproject.github.io.

This is what described in the official documentation "[Supported custom domains](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/about-custom-domains-and-github-pages)"

> After you configure a custom domain for a user or organization site, the custom domain will replace the `<user>.github.io` or `<organization>.github.io` portion of the URL for any project sites owned by the account that do not have a custom domain configured.
>
> For example, if the custom domain for your user site is `www.octocat.com`, and you have a project site with no custom domain configured that is published from a repository called `octo-project`, the GitHub Pages site for that repository will be available at `www.octocat.com/octo-project`.

That was reported as [an issue in 2016](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/547):

> I'm afraid this can't be disabled. If you have a CNAME file in a User pages site you other project pages will redirect to this Url.
>
> You can override it by adding a different CNAME to your project page though or just create another Project site to act as your user page.

In 2020, here is a possible workaround, mentioned by [Oliver Vorasai](https://github.com/OliverVorasai):

> ### The Problem
>
> - Have portfolio repository at https://github.com/username/username.github.io
> - https://github.com/username/username.github.io uses custom domain at `www.username.com`
> - Created *another* project at https://github.com/username/my-new-project
> - Create `gh-pages` branch so Github Pages will host it
> - `my-new-project` should be accessible at https://username.github.io/my-new-project/
> - https://username.github.io/my-new-project/ it is automatically redirected to [www.username.com/my-new-project](http://www.username.com/my-new-project) and causes 404.
>
> ### The Solution
>
> - Rename the https://github.com/username/username.github.io repository to https://github.com/username/username-something
> - https://github.com/username/my-new-project should now be available at https://username.github.io/my-new-project/
> - [www.username.com](http://www.username.com) is still working, subsequent projects should get standard Github Pages urls without custom domains.

Not ideal though, as mentioned by [Emma Sax](https://github.com/emmahsax) :

> I still think the best solution would be an option in the GH Pages settings of a project page to not redirect the domain of a project page.
>
> This way, users would have a choice of having `username.github.io/project-page` redirect to `www.customdomain.com/project-page` or having it stay where it is.
>
> It's frustrating to me that we even need to find an alternative solution at all.